# How to edit the home dock icons (shortcuts) on TouchWiz 4.0 ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, home-screen-shortcuts, samsung-galaxy-note, samsung-touchwiz

I recently received the ICS update to my Galaxy Note and couldn't (or couldn't remember how to) change the shortcut icons at the bottom of each page. It seems they have removed one method for changing them.

Answer (score 2):

1. Touch "Applications"
2. Touch Menu button
3. Touch "Grid View"
4. Touch Menu button
5. Touch "Edit"
6. Now you can drag and drop icons to/from shortcut bar